# Shopify POST credentials Authentication Error

Tags: authentication, post, shopify, token, credentials

I do have problems in connecting my Shopify Admin REST -API via my own Server.

Postman seems fine, with only the Access-Token.

What's wrong with my Code-Snippet? Did I use the wrong credentials?

It looks like that:

```
var settings = {
"url": "110a2*****:sh***@shop*****.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/custom_collections.json",
"method": "POST",
"timeout": 0,
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "json/application",
"Authorization": "Basic MTEwYTJiZWU1YjN********"
},
"data": " {\"custom_collection\": {\r\n \"title\": \"MacbooksTEST123456\",\r\n \"body_html\": \"Description of the collection\", \n \"sort_order\": \"manual\", \n \"template_suffix\": \"your_template_suffix\", \n \"published_scope\": \"web\"\r\n }}",
};


When I send my request in Postman, I receive a 200 Response and get redirected to the Login page of my shop, but nothing been uploaded/updated actually.


Here's my (anonymous) credentials:


API credentials

API key (=username)
110a***


API secret key
a41e***


API apiEndpointURL
https://shop***.myshopify.com/


Client credentials
Client ID
1bf1**


Client secret
d34**


The response looks like this:

{  
"responseCode": 401,
  "errorResponse": "{\"errors\":\"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)\"}"
}
```

Help's appreciated very much!

I reviewed the HTTP status codes and tried to use other credentials, with no positive results. In Postman it seems to work fine.